# Inject energy on a RLC circuit to mantain a sinusoidal

Tags: oscillator

I want to design an ideal RLC oscillator that generates a sinusoidal voltage and current waverforms. To accomplish this I must provide the energy lost in the resistor. I want to do it from a DC voltage source as simple as possible (with a simple switch?).

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This is usually done with an op amp, though the classic circuits (such as the Colpitts oscillator) use just a single transistor-slash-electron-tube.

Comment: @Felthry I'm targeting power electronics, so a power solution will be better. And the analysis should be ideal, so if possible, completely avoiding the complexity of a real active element.

Comment: Your above comment now makes the question unclear. Be very clear about your output requirements or add a power amplifier to a simple RLC oscillator.

Comment: You have no other choice - you must use an amplifier for establishing a positive feedback loop for the desired oscillating frequency (fulfilling Barkhausen`s oscillation condition).

Comment: If you want to make an inverter, this isn't the way to go about doing it.

Comment: @Felthry If I want to make an inverter I probably will just buy one. In the worst case I will copy an existing design. I'm just learning electronics. This is a theoretical exercise.